# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm

Tags: java, maven, jwt, openfire

I have created a plugin for openfire and this pluging using java-jwt , after adding plugin into openfire error is comming like this

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm

My pom file is include

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
     <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Please add the portion of configuration related to the build.
The error appear when you run the JAR or directly in your IDE?

Comment: Issue is resolved after adding java-jwt and depending jar files to directory is working

Comment: I am also facing same issue, any solution?

Comment: @Manish Issue is resolved after adding java-jwt and depending jar files to directory is working

Answer (score -1):

Just Restart your project or eclipse or Intellij IDE. After restart, run again the application and then it will work